# Determining if a class has a constructor method

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

How do I tell whether or not the class Animal or the class Mammal have constructors?

Animal a = new Mammal("Elephant");

Comment: Constructors are not methods, and if this code compiles then you are invoking the `Mammal` constructor which takes a `String`.

Comment: Open Mammal.java in a text editor and read it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Actually a constructor *is* a method, just not an  instance method.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Not according to the Java Language Specification.  Constructors are executable members like methods, but they are not methods.

Comment: You can just instantiate the Animal/Mammal object with no arguments and if it gives you an error it should tell you what kind of arguments it takes.

Comment: Another way to find out would be to generate the javadocs for the classes and read the javadocs.  And there are ways you do it using various IDEs, code analysis tools, reflection, etcetera.   But reading the source code is probably the simplest way.

Comment: @BrianGoetz They are methods by definition of a method in OOP.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek that's a slippery slope that you're climbing, and I've seen authoritative experts go both ways on this. Please let's avoid being overly didactic on a such trivial issue, and instead concern ourselves with the merit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question all classes must have at least one Constructor, even if it is not accessible to other classes.

You can identify a constructor that has been manually added by the developer, see below code example of a declared constructor. The comments explain how a constructor is declared.

```
public class Animal {

    /*
    *Constructors can be identified in code where the name is the same as the class and has no return type. 
    * The below constructor will require a String to be supplied in order to create an object of type animal.
    */
    public Animal(String name){
        //constructor code goes in here 
    }

}
```

Even if the class does not have a visibly declared constructor like the below example one will be generated by the JVM when compiling your class.

```
public class Animal {
    /*
     *Just because there is no visible constructor does not mean that one is not available, 
     *By default if no constructor is written a default no argument constructor will be provided after the code is compiled
     *Such that this class can be instantiated as such new Animal() 
     */
}
```

The default constructor in java will be public and have no arguments provided such that the above example can be instantiated as new Animal().

Finally to find out what constructors have been declared for a particular class you can make use of Java's reflection library, below is an example of how you can access each of the declared constructors.

```
public class PrintConstructorsForClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Constructor<?> constructor : Animal.class.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
            //Code to inspect each constructor goes in here. 
        }
    }
}
```